# Read response headers when using angular-spring-data-rest

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I am unable to find a way to read the response headers when using `SpringDataRestAdapter` and `$http`.  I can successfully read and process the response object, but I need to be able to store the ETag that is return in the HTTP Header.

I can't find any mention of HTTP Headers, anybody know how to get to them?

```
function getData(uri) {

  var deferred =  $http({
    method: 'Get',
    url: uri
  });

  return SpringDataRestAdapter.process(deferred).then(function (processedResponse) {

    return processedResponse;

  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to chain `then` to your `$http` GET call and use the result promise as an input to `SpringDataRestAdapter`. Something like this:

```
function getData(uri) {

  var deferred =  $http({
    method: 'Get',
    url: uri
  }).then(function(response) {
     // save ETag from response.headers
     ...

     return response;
  });

  return SpringDataRestAdapter.process(deferred).then(function (processedResponse) {

    return processedResponse;

  });

}
```

BTW, you can also use a shorthand for `$http` call:

```
$http.get(url).then(...)
```